# how to call global functions classes from namespace PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

Is there any way how to avoid to using so often backslash ?

Now if i'm using namespace and calling something global inside it i have to use backslash:

```
namespace foo;
$a = new \my\name(); // instantiates "my\name" class
echo \strlen('hi'); // calls function "strlen"
$a = \INI_ALL; // $a is set to the value of constant "INI_ALL"
```

in that case code inside namespace become really ugly, is there any way how to avoid that situation ???

The example was taken from that url: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php

But my problem in that, if I need call some built in class from namespace i have to use backslash in front of the name, can I  somehow avoid it ?

Comment: You do not need to prefix every built-in function of PHP.

Comment: [namespace documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) is really bad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

constants and functions from the global namespace do not have to be prepended with a backslash. PHP will fallback to the global namespace for those on it's own. There is a whole chapter in the PHP manual explaining this:

- [Using namespaces: fallback to global function/constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)

> Inside a namespace, when PHP encounters a unqualified Name in a class name, function or constant context, it resolves these with different priorities. Class names always resolve to the current namespace name. […] For functions and constants, PHP will fall back to global functions or constants if a namespaced function or constant does not exist.

Comment: Yep, and what should I do with exceptions, for instance, or any other buil in classes ? like memcached etc... ? it does not work if I call it without backslash even php builded extension class. It means in code there are a lot of back slashes :(

Comment: @user1016265 an exception is neither a function, nor a constant but a class and the manual clearly states that class names resolve to the current namespace name so you have to prepend them or alias them on top of your script.

Comment: You do however need to add the backslash infront of "native" class like `\Exception`, `\Memcached` or you can choose to add: `use \Exception;` to the top of your file. Then you can use `new Exception('..');` without the backslash.

Comment: @Gordon that PHP manual fully crap. What solution do you think better, what Michael suggested or manual described ? My opinion Michael suggestion better in 100%

Comment: @user1016265 what Michael describes is the same that I describe is the same that the Manual describes. We all describe the same thing because we bothered to read and understand the manual.

Comment: @Gordon in the link what you had provide me, in your first answer, no any solution what i was looked for. Moreover solution described in manual, like: "extending built in class to get access to it without backslash" - fully crap! You could compare your self that two different approach.

Comment: @user well, you asked about functions and constants. I gave you the appropriate manual entry for that. You only asked about exceptions afterwards. If you had actually bothered to go through the chapters in http://php.net/namespaces, especially the chapter about aliasing, you wouldn't have had to ask at all. So please do youself a favor and read those chapters instead of claiming the php manual to be full of crap when it's really just you not looking properly.

Comment: @Gordon I don't want to argue with you, but seems to me, you and me we are reading different PHP manual :) And even my topic subject classname is mentioned. Never mind. PHP manual is suck.

Comment: @user well, in any case: did my answer solve your problem? if so, please accept it or point out why it doesnt help you, so I can consider changing it.

Comment: @Gordon after reading manual twice I understood that my question was a bit wrong, and this is why your answer was not full for me. Thanks, but PHP manual really has a lot of mistakes even in one namespace section (couple pages).