# What is the "use function" expression?

Tags: php

I saw this snippet and I dont understand why used 
`use function array_map` expression ?

```
<?php

namespace Project\MyProject;

use function array_map;

class MyProjectClass 
{
    protected $arr = [];
    public function __construct(array $arr)
    {
        $this->arr = array_map('trim', $arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Well it imports a function.

Comment: It's redundant in this case. Global functions will be looked up implicitly. Importing functions is a non-measurable performance thing. The parens `()` behind the class name are a syntax error, btw.

Comment: @simon it work fine without import function

Comment: @mario sorry, the parens () it my fault, it not relative to the question

Comment: Nevermind; was just a marginal note. // See also [how to call global functions classes from namespace PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/12157238) → which explains the syntax/behaviour. `Use function` mostly makes sense for aliasing from distinct namespaces. For global indentifiers it's arguably just a style choice, some IDEs even inject this automatically. - So is your question about the syntax/semantics? Or about the rationale? (That would mean opinionated answers.)

Comment: @mario I want to know about rationale. I think write every time `Use function` for all standard functions its extra work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in [how to call global functions classes from namespace PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12157238):

```
use function array_map;
```

aliases a global function into the local namespace.

- This is generally unneeded.
- PHP looks up functions in the global scope anyway.
- It only makes sense if you were to redeclare a global function in the current namespace.

  - Which is somewhat of a rare situation.
  - But if you had (this is called "monkey patching") then you also wouldn't want to undermine it with `use function`.

The real reason `use function` was introduced is:

- For actually aliasing / renaming functions:

  - `use function App\Helpers\my_mappymcmapface as array_map;`
  - `use function \trim as chomp;`
- And also because PHP coders have been littering their codebases with `\trim` and `\strpos` before.

  - That was one of those unwarranted micro-performance optimizations.

So yes, for this case it's pointless decoration.