# How do I call ngettext() from a static function in PHP

Tags: php

I am writing a class that contains static functions.  One of these functions calls [ngettext()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ngettext.php).

```
<?php
namespace UTILS;

    class StringUtils
    {
        public static function generateMessage($object_count){
            $message = "There " . ngettext("is", "are", $object_count) . " $object_count objects.";
        }
    }
?>
```

When called, I am receiving an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function UTILS\ngettext()
```

If this is a function built into PHP, why is it failing here and what can I do to correct this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php `\ngettext`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call global functions classes from namespace PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157238/how-to-call-global-functions-classes-from-namespace-php)

Comment: Did you check with phpinfo(), if your php version is compiled with gettext library

Comment: @cske: \ngettext did not work.  It now says "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ngettext()".

Comment: @ivion:  my php version is compiled with the gettext library

Comment: Is it just a Typo in the question, or did you forget one closing }.

Comment: Typo, thanks for pointing it out.  I have updated the example code